# Language redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have two versions of the same page:

- example.com
- example.com/fr  -> French version

I would like French people who access to mydomain.com to be redirected to mydomain.com/fr based on the header Accept-language. To do that I wrote this into my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/fr/ [L,R=301]
```

I works perfect so far.

But in my site there are links to the French / English versions... When a French user who is in the French version clicks on the english link, he comes back to the french version... How can I avoid this? **How can I distinguish he actually wants to go to the English version?**

Comment: you shouldn't use .htaccess for this or you need to set a different header for each new request after clicking a new language. I'd like to use a cookie to store the lang and doing the redirect in the app instead the .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

A Suggestion may be to include links to the top of your page - each to different pages, for example; FR - mydomain.com/fr, ENG - mydomain.com/eng

Depending on the context of the website - I would then set either the French or English versions of the website as the default.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a parameter on the query string to the internal language links, to prevent the normal language redirection from happening when the user has clicked a link to a specific language.

Then add an extra RewriteCond to your .htaccess to check whether the user has clicked an internal link:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(nolangredirect=1)
```

So if a French user clicks on `www.example.com/en/index.html?nolangredirect=1` they will not be redirected to the French version.

If you want them to see the English version next time they come back to the website, you'll need to use cookies.